# Zero Interest is causing me more harm than riba, is it the right choice?

Tags: riba

I had to purchase a car, but did not wanted with riba, so the only option was to purchase a new car which I has at 0%, BUT monthly I have now to find a large sum of money which is causing me a lot of trouble. With a used car I could have a with quarter the price I'm paying per month.to clarify more I dont have cash to purchase a car. SO my question is it worth having no riba and causing me financial problems for the coming 5 years?

Answer (score 2):

I do not need to give detailed references here because I think this is not just about Islam but also about personal finance and money. I will try to be very frugal in my response and I mean no disrespect but Islam teaches us to live within our means and if you do not have money for a new car then do not purchase a new car.

Quran - Surah Furqan (25:67) - "And [they are] those who, when they spend, do so not excessively or sparingly but are ever, between that, [justly] moderate"

Hadith - Prophet Muhammad (SAW) - "O Allah, suffice me with what You have allowed instead of what You have forbidden, and make me independent of all others besides You."
At-Tirmidhi 5/560. See also Al-Albani, Sahih At-Tirmidhi 3/180.

Instead you should try and find alternatives like public transport, car-pooling with colleagues or ride-sharing services. If you do not have an alternative and must own a car then purchase a used car or rent a car until you can afford to own one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question earlier, but just I posted it, Allah gave me the answer! Yes its better to endure some difficulties for the pleasure of Allah, I believe that after a period of test, Allah will make my situation better, because I did it only for His pleasure and I'm sure HE will not let me down(Ameen)

Comment: It seems to me that expecting Allah to help you is a little presumptuous. Worldly affairs are our responsibility.

Comment: This is bad advice. You are advocating financial burden on the OP which may cause him to develop health problems, stress and can even create problems at home.

Comment: @masfenix this answer is written by the OP